# Ruby gem to access excel graphical objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, excel, rubygems

I have an Excel document. I want access graphical objects(such as charts, diagrams, images etc) and store it in ruby variables. Tried the same with Spreadsheet and roo gem, but ths gems does not support accessing graphical objects.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing Excel data from Ruby can be a bit painful. I would suggest you export/import the raw data from the Excel sheets, and construct the Charts with some JavaScript library such as:

- http://raphaeljs.com/
- http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/
- https://developers.google.com/chart/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) with the gem [rjb](http://rjb.rubyforge.org/).

Install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jdk
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
$ sudo apt-get install ant
$ gem install "rjb"
```

Use:

```
require 'rjb'

#RJM Loading
JARS = Dir.glob('./jar/*.jar').join(':')
Rjb::load(JARS, ['-Xmx512M'])

# Classes:
# Java
file_input_class = Rjb::import('java.io.FileInputStream')
file_output_class = Rjb::import('java.io.FileOutputStream')
byte_array_output_class = Rjb::import('java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream')

# POI
workbook_factory_class = Rjb::import('org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory')

file_in_path = "./chart1.xlsx"
file_in = file_input_class.new(file_in_path)
wb = workbook_factory_class.create(file_in)
sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0)
charts = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch().getCharts()
p chart1.getClass().getName() # First chart's name
```

Comment: thnks bro.. Do u hv an example in using jruby ?

Comment: there is the gem [jruby-poi](https://github.com/kameeoze/jruby-poi), but I not used this... you can get the docs in http://poi.apache.org/apidocs